# Add barlegend colored by area of circle

Tags: plotting, legending

I am using the following code where color and color barlegend show the radius of the concentric circles:

```
ClearAll[b]
b[x_] := x

Legended[
 Graphics[
   Table[{Hue[i/20], Circle[{0, 0}, b[i]]}, {i, 1, 6, 0.1}],
   ImageSize -> 350, Frame -> True
 ],
 BarLegend[{Hue[#/20] &, {1, 6}}]
]
```

Can the code be adapted to show the area of the circles instead?

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[b]
b[x_] = x;
Legended[Graphics[
  Table[{Hue[π*i^2/(π*6^2)], Circle[{0, 0}, b[i]]}, {i, 1, 6, 
    0.1}], ImageSize -> 350, Frame -> True], 
 BarLegend[{Hue[#/(π*6^2)] &, π {1, 6}^2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I am using it like this . 
    Now how to set barlegend numbers according to the c[x] value?
     c[x_] := (1 - 0.01/x^2)/(
  4 \[Pi] Sqrt[(1 - 0.0005/x) (1 - x/20)] x);
b[x_] = x;
Legended[Graphics[
  Table[{Hue[c[i]/(9*c[6])], Circle[{0, 0}, b[i]]}, {i, 1, 6, 0.1}], 
  ImageSize -> 350, Frame -> True], 
 BarLegend[{Hue[c[#]/(9*c[6])] &, {1, 6}}]]